# How can I turn off vibration without going into silent mode on a rooted Nexus 5 with stock firmware?

Tags: root-access, 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5, vibration, xposed-framework

I see a [related question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52416/turn-off-vibration-notification-for-all-apps-at-once) but I do not see an applicable answer to my exact situation. I want to turn off vibration on notifications, without diabling notification sound along (so notifications should still play sound, just not vibrate).

I'd like to do it using Tasker. @Izzy recommended the "Vibrate On Notify" toggle but that doesn't seem to be available for me; unsure as to why (see image below).

I'd be open to installing Xposed Frameworks module if needed. Any ideas?

[image: tasker window]
<sup>*Tasker* window (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Have you tried to go to User Profile settings and changing the Default Notification to Silent?

Comment: Have you tried Tasker's *Vibrate On Notify* action? From the [Tasker manual](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/help/ah_index.html): *Whether to vibrate with a system notification.* I've not tried it, but it sounds fitting.

Comment: @shub but wouldn't that also suppress notification volume? As far as I understand the question, OP only wants to turn vibration for notifications off, not volume.

Comment: @Izzy correct; I'd like to turn it off _without_ going into silent. I looked at the mentioned tasker option but it is not available to me for some reason. Looked promising.

Comment: Yeah, some options seem to be device specific. I've got some of those as well. Usually this means the device doesn't support that.

Comment: Have you tried the search function in the [Xposed modules repository](http://repo.xposed.info/module-overview)? A quick check found no exact matches, but some modules which *might* include it.

Comment: @Izzy yes, did a search on Xposed and didn't find anything applicable.

Comment: @BeamingMel-Bin A comparable issue: On some devices it's not possible to disable cell radio without going into airplane mode. My work-around here: Switch to airplane mode, and then explicitly enable everything I didn't want to switch off (e.g. WiFi, Bluetooth). Not sure if a similar thing would be possible here (switching to silent mode, and then turn on volumes only), so it's just a thought in which direction some rescue *might* be.

Comment: @Izzy i have already tried that one out but didn't work for me. That's why did not post.

Answer (score 1):

[Install Vibration Tuner Xposed module](http://repo.xposed.info/module/ztc1997.vibrationtuner) and set "global vibration strength" to `0%`.

Compatible with at least Android 5-7 (I don't personally own a device with Oreo installed).