# Notification vibration of Nougat system

Tags: 7.0-nougat

In the Nougat version of the Android system is it possible to disable the notification vibration?

Comment: Refer to https://android.stackexchange.com/a/118817/96277. Should be compatible with Android 7 I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are 2 ways to achieve your goal:

- Hold the notification and select `Show notifications silently`, then press `Done`
- Go to `Settings` -> `Apps` -> choose the app you want to mute -> `Notifications`, then toggle `Show silently` option.

You have to do this for every app you want to be silent, as notifications are handled per app. This will prevent them from making sound, vibration or peeking.