# How to turn off incoming text message notification vibration off in Android 10?

Tags: notifications, sms, settings, vibration, android-10

I would like to turn off vibrations for incoming message on Google Pixel 1, default SMS app, and I can't find a way to do this.

I searched several places, mostly messages app settings and general phone notifications settings (which anyway redirects me to the first one). There is no *general* setting under *notifications* there and I can't see anything about vibrations.

It seems this app does not provide a way to control vibrations, and there is no system option to forbid them, but it seems hard to believe.

Comment: I know I can turn all vibrations off (https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52416/turn-off-vibration-notification-for-all-apps-at-once), but I wonder if it's possible only for this app.